# Django and phpBB server

Tags: php, django

Is it possible to integrate Django web site and PHP forum by some apache directive in httpd.conf file? For example:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myserver
DocumentRoot home/myserver/www/
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myserver/www/mywebsite/mywebsite/wsgi.py
<Directory "home/myserver/www/mywebsite">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
Alias /forum/ /home/myserver/www/mywebsite/forum/
<Directory /home/myserver/www/mywebsite/forum>
    *tell apache it's PHP*
</Directory>`

I've seen this question, but no one said anything about directives..

Answer (score 0):

`<Directory /home/myserver/www/mywebsite/forum>
        suPHP_UserGroup myuser myuser
</Directory>`

solved it.